# MongoDB, Group by accumulated field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I searched the net but couldn't find an answer, is this possible in MongoDB?

If I have a collection of

```
Orders{
    _id
    timestamp
    orderNumber
    numberItems
    pricePerItem
}
```

Can I group them by a fixed accumulated value of a field?

For instance, if I have

```
orders: {
    _id:1,
    timestamp:222,
    orderNumber:1,
    numberItems:3,
    pricePerItem:10
},
{
    _id:2,
    timestamp:333,
    orderNumber:2,
    numberItems:5,
    pricePerItem:14
},
{
    _id:3,
    timestamp:444,
    orderNumber:3,
    numberItems:2,
    pricePerItem:12
},...
```

Can I group them by a group of N orders, where the sum of numberItems = 50, ordered by arrival (orderNumber, that is incremented for every order)? 
And maybe calculate the average price of the items, and maybe keep the timestamp of the first order

```
batch: {
    _id:1,
    timestamp:222,
    batchNumber:1,
    numberItemsInBatch:50,
    priceAvg:12
},
{
    _id:2,
    timestamp:555,
    batchNumber:2,
    numberItemsInBatch:50,
    priceAvg:13
},...
```

Comment: You need to be more specific. Which 50 items? Is there something we are supposed to use for selection or are you just talking at random?

Comment: A clear sample would come to a total based on the documents you supply in the question. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the help center. Your question should leave no doubt to the people who would answer it.

Comment: You can `$sort` by order number followed by `$limit` and `$group` with `$avg` & `$first` to calculate average price of items and keep the timestamp of first order respectively.

Comment: Thank you for the answer,
but $limit will limit the number of document fetched, so if you specify 
{ $limit : 50 } then you will only get the first 50 orders.
The challenge is to get N orders where order1.numberItems + order2.numberItems + order3.numberItems + ....  = 50 and group them, then continue with the next batch where the sum of numberItems is 50, and so on...